# Is it possible to retrieve a shortcut location and use it as a variable in the target of itself?

Tags: windows, script, environment-variables, path, shortcuts

I created a VBS script (C:\Script\ReadFolder.vbs) that accept a folder path as parameter.

I would like to create a shortcut to run this script in different folders.

First, I created a shortcut in "C:\Temp" to run the script in this folder so I set the target of the shortcut to :
`C:\Script\ReadFolder.vbs "C:\Temp\"`.

Then I create another shortcut in "C:\Test" to run the script in this folder so I set the target to `C:\Script\ReadFolder.vbs "C:\Test\"`.

I would like to create a shortcut that I just have to copy to any folder and it would use the shortcut location folder as parameter for my VBS script as target (i.e. `C:\Script\ReadFolder.vbs %SHORTCUTPATH%`).

Is there a was to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the parameter reference inside your script by
just `.` for the current folder.

Comment: This won't work. The "." will refer to the folder where the script is located not the folder where the shortcut is.

Comment: You could perhaps use a `.bat` file instead of a shortcut.

Comment: A .bat does what I wanted but I would like to know if it's possible to do the same with a shortcut...

Comment: I don't think so. The only way I know to pass a folder is using the "Send to" context menu of Explorer.